# Aligning Cells without Overlap

Tags: tables, vertical-alignment

I'm having trouble with my table because the contents of the second cell are overlapping into the top cell.  I assume that I have to expand the width of the cells or bottom align the content of the cells, but I'm not sure how to do this.  Thank you for your help.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{amsmath, amsfonts, empheq}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}
\usepackage{tabularx}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[ht]
\centering
\begin{adjustbox}{width=.8\textwidth}
\begin{tabular}[b]{clll}
  \hline
  Performance Variables \\ 
  \hline
 $\begin{aligned}
  Annual Return &= \frac{Stock\,Price_t\,-\,Stock\,Price_{t-1}}{Stock\,Price_{t-1}} \\[20pt]
  Tobin's\,Q &= \frac{Equity\,Market\,Value\,+\,Liabilities\,Book\,Value}{Equity\,Book\,Value \,+\,Liabilities\,Book\,Value}\\[20pt]
  ROA &= \frac{Net\,Income}{Total\,Assets} \\[20pt]
   \hline
   \end{aligned}$
\end{tabular}
\end{adjustbox}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image: a busy cat]

Comment: Please add a complete (but minimal) code example. Right now we/I have to guess what packages you use.

Comment: After `Performance Variables \\ \hline`, you can add `\\[-10pt]` (or some other negative number) to add a thin vertical space.

Comment: It looks like you've got two separate accounts, which means you cannot edit your original post or leave comments. The Stack Exchange staff can [merge them together for you](//tex.stackexchange.com/help/user-merge).

Answer (score 3):

Here is a very simple solution with `booktabs`, which adds some (adjustable) vertical padding around its rules, and has a `addlinespace` command. I tool the liberty to put the fractions argument in text mode, to have a correct interletter spacing (otherwise, letters are spaced as a product of variables, and typed in maths italic):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{amsfonts, empheq}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage[a4paper, showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{tabularx, booktabs}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[ht]
\centering
\begin{adjustbox}{width=.8\textwidth}
\begin{tabular}[b]{c*{3}{l}}
  \toprule
  Performance Variables \\
  \midrule
\addlinespace
 $\begin{aligned}
  \text{Annual Return} &= \frac{\text{Stock\,Price}_t-\text{Stock Price}_{t-1}}{\text{Stock Price}_{t-1}} \\
\addlinespace
  \text{Tobin's Q} &= \frac{\text{Equity Market Value} + \text{Liabilities Book Value}}{\text{Equity Book Value} + \text{Liabilities Book Value}}\\
\addlinespace
  \text{ROA} &= \frac{\text{Net Income}}{\text{Total Assets}} \\
\addlinespace
   \bottomrule
   \end{aligned}$
\end{tabular}
\end{adjustbox}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

> You are new here. Normally people here expect a complete code with the minimal code that is required to reproduce the problem. In your case this was only `adjustbox` and `amsmath` package and the `\documentclass` of course.

**I added a invisible vertical rule `\rule`** and I used `\text{}` inside the equation ty typeset the variables appropriately (but this has npthing to do with your question). `$Stock$` means `S \times t \times o ...` and so on, whereas $\text{Stock}$ is one variable, at least that is the convention I know (check with your supervisor).

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{adjustbox} 

\begin{document}

% nothing changed
\begin{equation}
\boxed{\frac{\text{Stock\,Price}_{t-1}}{\text{Stock\,Price}_t - \text{Stock\,Price}_{t-1}}}
\end{equation}

% visible \rule, width = 1 pt
\begin{equation}
\boxed{\frac{\rule[0pt]{1pt}{12pt}\text{Stock\,Price}_{t-1}}{\text{Stock\,Price}_t - \text{Stock\,Price}_{t-1}}}
\end{equation}

% invisible \rule
\begin{equation}
\boxed{\frac{\rule[0pt]{0pt}{12pt}\text{Stock\,Price}_{t-1}}{\text{Stock\,Price}_t - \text{Stock\,Price}_{t-1}}}
\end{equation}

\begin{table}[ht]
\centering
\begin{adjustbox}{width=.8\textwidth}
\begin{tabular}[b]{clll}
  \hline
  Performance Variables \\ 
  \hline
 $\begin{aligned}
  Annual Return &= \frac{\rule[0pt]{0pt}{12pt}Stock\,Price_t\,-\,Stock\,Price_{t-1}}{Stock\,Price_{t-1}} \\[20pt]
  Tobin's\,Q &= \frac{Equity\,Market\,Value\,+\,Liabilities\,Book\,Value}{Equity\,Book\,Value \,+\,Liabilities\,Book\,Value}\\[20pt]
  ROA &= \frac{Net\,Income}{Total\,Assets} \\[20pt]
   \hline
   \end{aligned}$
\end{tabular}
\end{adjustbox}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

A supplement to nice *Dr. Manuel Kuehner* answer. In mine I give accents on the following:

- in your table you use one column, not four, as you declare in tabular preamble
- displayed equations and column types `c`, `l` and `r` don't like each other very much, correct is use `parbox` column type as `p{} and similar
- in your equations are text and not collection of variables.Therefore is more correct to write for example `$\textit{some text}$` `as`some\,text$`
- more beautiful results can be obtained by use of rules from `booktabs` package

Considering above, I suggest to use `tabularx` package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsfonts, empheq}
\usepackage{booktabs,tabularx}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[ht]
    \centering
\begin{tabularx}{0.8\textwidth}{X}
  \toprule
  Performance Variables \\
  \midrule
  \addlinespace
$\begin{aligned}
\textit{Annual Return}  & = \frac{\textit{Stock Price}_t - \textit{Stock Price}_{t-1}}
                                 {\textit{Stock Price}_{t-1}}                                       \\[1ex]
    \textit{Tobin's Q}  & = \frac{\textit{Equity Market Value} + \textit{Liabilities Book Value}}
                                 {\textit{Equity Book Value} + \textit{Liabilities Book Value}}    \\[1ex]
        \textit{ROA}    & = \frac{\textit{Net Income}}
                                 {\textit{Total Assets}}
\end{aligned}$   \\
  \addlinespace
   \bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Note; for roman type of text in above equations, just replace `\textit` with `\text`

Comment: You're making me blush all over ;). And I didn't know that one can use `\textit` in math mode.